# Why Faces Message did not show up on some pages even method is called?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, message

I have multiple pages, and on some, the FacesMessage appears, while on others they don't. But I can't figure out why. In my example below, ajax is at `false`, but on some ajax is at `true` like everywhere else, but not working even it's same code

In every case the method is called, log proves it, but the message did not show in some case

I have a menu bar, which is included on top of every page, as

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xlmns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xlmns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xlmns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xlmns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
       <f:facet name="first"> 
            <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>LOG</title>
        </f:facet>
        <h:body>
            <p:growl showDetail="true" sticky="true">  
                <p:autoUpdate disabled="false" /> 
            </p:growl>
            ...
            <p:layout>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <ui:insert name="center" />
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </h:body>
      </f:view>
</html>
```

And working page is like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<ui:composition template="/menu.xhtml"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
         xlmns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xlmns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
         xlmns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xlmns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:define name="center>
        <h:form >
            <p:commandButton action="#{firstBean.method()}" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Not working page is like (here ajax at false, but there is also non-working page with ajax true) :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<ui:composition template="/menu.xhtml"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
         xlmns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xlmns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
         xlmns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xlmns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:define name="center>
        <h:form enctype="mulipart/form-data" >
            <h:inputFile value="#{secondBean.inputFile}" />
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{secondBean.method()}"  process="@form" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And both `method()` are 100% same :

```
public void method(){
    new JSFUtils().sendMessage("Test 1");
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().severe("Test"); // Always worked, always called
    //...
}
```

Where I have an util class

```
public calss JSFUtil{
    public void sendMessage(String msg){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(Faces.Message.SEVERITY_WARN, "Warn", msg));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an autoupdate disabled in growl, did you try with updating the growl on the commandButtons?

Comment: @SergioDanielCoronelMalvarez disable is at `false` so it's enable

Comment: Just thinking out loud i wonder if its related to  `<h:form enctype="mulipart/form-data" >` your form being a mutlipart?

Comment: @Melloware I tried to remove, doesn't change, and I have other pages wihtout it and with ajax true and they also not-work. Code is the same in working, and non-working case, I've no idea what to do^^

Comment: You are right. Also in the second example you are making a partial process specifying the form. If you're using Ajax, then make sure that the UIInput and UICommand components of interest are covered by the process. By default p:commandButton does a process @all (first example).

Comment: There is this post from BalusC which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value/2120183#2120183

Comment: @SergioDanielCoronelMalvarez the method is invoked, I'll edit with this info

Comment: If you add an update of the growl in the ajax alternatives of the second example it doesn´t work?

Comment: The second example is ajax="false" so update="" and process="" are completely ignored for ajax="false" its a full form submit and page reload.

Comment: Yes, but he said that the second example doesn´t work even with ajax = true. Agree that it makes no sense to have both ajax and process in the component.

Comment: Try without a layout (won't make a difference I think but you should **always**... make the code you post a [mcve]).

Comment: @SergioDanielCoronelMalvarez: _"Agree that it makes no sense to have both ajax and process in the component."_ I agree, but it nowhere is explicitly stated that there is no bug that makes it behave differently than expected

Comment: @Kukeltje without a layout ? hum ?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, which makes putting both in the component a potential cause of behaviour change on different version.